# Instead of having different size_t variables, can I use just one for searching a std::string multiple times?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if it is possible to cut down how many size_t variables I use here. Here is what I have:

```
std::size_t found, found2, found3, found4 /* etc */;
```

Each has its own string to find:

```
found1 = msg.find("string1");
found2 = msg.find("string2");
found3 = msg.find("string3");
found4 = msg.find("string4");
// etc
```

If the word is found, then it will discard and prevent the message to be shown:

```
if (found1 != std::string::npos)
{
    SendMsg("You cannot say that word!");
}
```

I have else if statements until found21. I'd like to cut everything down in size, so it would be clean, but I don't have a clue how to do it. I would also like it to lowercase the word. I have never used tolower at all either, so I would appreciated it if someone would help me.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that your code snippet is on its way to thedailywtf.com

Comment: -1 for an invalid comment. Perhaps giving an open idea of what to do and stop with the comments that aren't really relevant to this thread? @Dave: I've used a loop before, but I don't know how to express it.

Comment: @Tommy: I believe you haven't read [the relevant The Daily WTF article](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-WET-Cart.aspx).

Comment: 1) No offense intended:  It's hard to know what you don't know.  This question shows you know there's a better way but need help finding it.  2) "I don't read that crap" -- without debating the merits of thedailywtf, let me say that reading other people's code (good and bad) is a big part of becoming a better programmer.

Comment: this is well on it's way to becoming a clbuttic code snippet.

Comment: @Ben: That is what stackoverflow is for. So people can help other people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To lowercase a string, you can do

```
std::transform(msg.begin(), msg.end(), msg.begin(), std::tolower);
```

Transform takes a begin and end iterator as the first and second arguments, and for each element in that range, applies the fourth argument (a function) and assigns it to what the third iterator is pointing to and increments it. By passing `msg.begin()` as both the first and third arguments, it will assign the result of the function to what it passed to it. So `transform` will basically do this:

```
for (auto src = begin(msg), dst = begin(msg); src != end(msg); ++src, ++dst)
    *dst = tolower(*src);
```

but using `transform` is so much nicer.

To check whether a string contains any of a list of substrings, you can use a `for` loop with a `vector`:

```
vector<string> bad_strings { "bad word 1", "bad word 2", "etc" };

for (auto i = begin(bad_strings); i != end(bad_strings); ++i)
    if (msg.find(*i)) {
        SendMsg("You cannot say that word!");
        break; // stop when you find it matches even one bad string
    }
```

Comment: I'd break out of the loop after finding a badword.

Comment: @Xeo okay, initially I didn't because he didn't in his example but I guess it won't hurt.

Comment: Also, if you're using C++11 features like `auto`, you may as well use the more modern `begin(bad_strings)`/`end(bad_strings)` iterator form as well. As an added benefit, it would work for dasblinkenlight's static-array answer as well.

Comment: @Novelocrat alright, I don't know what features are commonly supported and not, but if `begin` and `end` are supported by compilers that support `auto` then I'll use them.

Comment: I'm assuming a vector can be an array for strings? What he has above doesn't look like it will work correctly.

Comment: @TommyCooper If you mean "can a `vector` hold `string`s" then the answer is yes. If not, I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean. And yes, this code will work correctly assuming you have a recent compiler. If you don't, only small modifications need be made.

Comment: vector<string> bad_strings { "bad word 1", "bad word 2", "etc" };
I'm saying that will error, giving you: "'bad_strings' : local function definitions are illegal", "this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched", "error C2065: 'bad_strings' : undeclared identifier", "error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'", etc.

Comment: @TommyCooper that is a feature of C++11 (called uniform initialisation) that your compiler apparently doesn't support. You could either use `string bad_strings[] = { "bad word 1", "etc" };` or `vector<string> bad_words; bad_words.push_back("bad word 1"); bad_words.push_back("etc");` depending on how much you dislike arrays. The `for` loop will still work no matter which you use.

Comment: @Seth: Your last comment pretty much sums up why I didn't immediately answer this:  If someone needs help with a *loop* then introducing C++ vectors of strings with an initializer is going to require a lot of explaining.  The C++11 version is much nicer, at least.

Comment: All you have to do is explain the for loop including the vector. I know everything else.

Comment: @TommyCooper its a fairly straightforward loop, please elaborate on what exactly you would like to be explained.

Comment: Well, something is wrong with the code above, or with something, I don't know. Every time I go into my game and say something, my word gets block that isn't supposed to be blocked. The only way a word will work is if I push_back every word. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/w8BS4Hb7

Comment: Fixed it. if (msg.find(*i)) Should've been if (!msg.find(*i))! THANKS. I will press the checkmark!

Comment: Actually, it does work, but it doesn't check a whole sentence for the word.

Comment: @TommyCooper your code is wrong; that will cause your player to say the text for every iteration of the loop until a bad word is found, and also it should _not_ be `if  (!msg.find(*i))` because that means it will tell the player they can't say the word if it _does not_ find the bad word. I modified it a little based on how you are actually using it. It should be like this: http://pastebin.com/SVKx1zgs